# Drupal console "settings:set" not working or I am doing it wrong

Tags: 8, console

I wanted to use Drupal console to change some settings on a site:

- To set the default 403 page to "/user/login"
- To set user registration permission to "admin only"

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/settings-set.html), which gives this example:

```
drupal settings:set  application.language es
```

I tried the following:

```
drupal settings:set user.settings.register admin_only
drupal settings:set user.settings register:admin_only
drupal settings:set user.settings.register "admin_only"
```

In all cases, I got a green bar saying that the setting had been successfully set. But looking at the site showed that it had not. Also doing `drupal config:edit user.settings` showed that it had not (but when I changed it in the editor, it did update successfully in real life).

The exact same thing happened with:

```
drupal settings:set system.site.page.403 /user/login
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an unimplemented part of drupal console?

Comment: Those instructions relate to the console's own settings file I think. Config edit is the way to do it using drupal console. If you want a one-liner, drush cset provides one.

Comment: Perfect! "drush cset user.settings register admin_only -y" works a treat. Please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have done so, @naomi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "drupal settings:set" command updates the Drupal console's own settings rather than the configuration of the running Drupal site.

If you want a one-liner to update configuration, then you can use [Drush](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-set/) for this job, eg:

```
drush cset user.settings register admin_only -y
```